# Method Illuminate\Support\Str::replace does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using:

- Laravel Version: 8.35.1
- PHP Version: 7.4.9

On Tinker and Routing I use `Str::replace()` method as in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-replace) but get error:

> BadMethodCallException with message Method Illuminate\Support\Str::replace does not exist.

Example 1:

```
root@c6dd4af63e3c:/var/www/html# php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.7 (PHP 7.4.9 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Illuminate\Support\Str::replace('8.x', '9.x', 'Laravel 8.x');
BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate\Support\Str::replace does not exist.'
>>>
```

Example2:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return Illuminate\Support\Str::replace('8.x', '9.x', 'Laravel 8.x');
});
```

Why do I have this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String Replace method `Illuminate\Support\Str::replace` introduced in Laravel version `v8.41.0`

[image]

Ref:https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.41.0